# HC-12 detection by Raspberry Pi bluetooth scanner

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I have bought an HC-12 module, but as much as I have investigated I have not found a way that a Raspberry Pi with a bluetooth detector called bluelog can detect it.

What do I have to do so that HC-12 wired to a Arduino can be detected with the bluetooth scanner?

How to set HC-12 in 'discoverable' mode?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know why everyone freaks about this HC-12 module but it's not compatible with Bluetooth. It's just a UART transceiver...

Comment: @KingDuken it's cheap and it's sold with misleading descriptions such as "Replace Bluetooth Antenna"

Answer (score 1):

The HC-12 is not a bluetooth device, but a 433 MHz transceiver wrapped by an MCU running who knows what firmware.

You've likely been hoodwinked by a misleading listing on an e-commerce site where these are often promoted with wording such as "Replace Bluetooth Antenna" where the truth is that they are at best an *alternative* to a bluetooth serial link which will only work if you use something like or compatible with this on *both* ends.

In theory if you put another on your pi, that *might* work, but you'd be at the mercy of whatever link semantics and assumptions are built into that MCU firmware; bluetooth and BLE serial are far from perfect either, but are at least *documented* and have broad hardware compatibility.

Generally speaking, one should only buy electronic modules off e-commerce sites if you can either recognize exactly what you are getting, or where you've read technical writeups by others explaining what the device really is and its capabilities/flaws *as documented by those third parties* make it seem useful.

That said, while there's a technical point that can be made, the question is an off-topic "usage" one which may end up closed.